# Methods for parsing C++ defines?

Tags: c++

I'm building a driver in C++ which relies heavily on another dll (surprise!).  This dll comes with a header which contains a huge list of defines.  Each define represents different return, message and error codes.

Each of these sets of defines has a prefix which differentiates it from the others.  Something like:

MSG_GOOD... MSG_BAD... MSG_INDIFFERENT...

RETURN_OK... RETURN_OMG.. RETURN_WHAT...

But hundreds of them.  This makes things rather hard to debug.

Ideally, I'd like to find a way to get some kind of reasonable log output with plain text.  I was thinking it might be possible to parse the H file at run time, but a less complex compile time option would be much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll have to parse the .h file at one point or another, because once compiled, the #defines won't be anywhere in the code anymore. Parsing .h files just for the #defines isn't too hard though - just read in full lines (mind the backslash at the end), `ltrim` them, and if they begin with `"#define "` then `split` the remainder at the first whitespace, `trim` both parts, stuff them in a key/value container and you're essentially done. Shouldn't be too hard even in C++.

Comment: Perhaps the output of this processing might be an enum definition, which can be fed back into the project...